# How do is export a layer with icon from photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, png, sprite, image-sprite

I have an icon like this:

[image]

It's on its own layer with a tranpsarent background, I duplicate it onto a new layer.

I can't remember how to *fit* a rectangular selection around it, so that it is just the right size, so I could then export it as a .png?

I also have a few icons like that, each on their own layer. How would I go about making them into a sprite image?

Comment: I believe cmd+click on the layer in the layers panel makes a selection that fits the layer

Comment: CAI is correct. Or ctrl-click te layer thumb on Windows. In CC you can right-click a layer and export it directly.

Comment: galdikas, you should mark one of these as the correct answer or tell everyone why these two didn't work for you. Otherwise, you might never get additional answers. This question has been bumped to the front page by the community bot like 24 times (did a quick count from the edits). — There are definitely better answers to this question, but many people don't like tho answer questions that seem to be abandoned by the op. You never commented on the given answers saying why they didn't work for you so maybe they did... maybe they didn't... who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command–click to select the layer. Then select the crop tool (hit "C"). If the crop tool isn't the current tool, then it should crop to the selection. If it *is* the current tool simply pick something else, like the move tool (hit "V"), and then pick the crop tool again. Hit enter to crop the image. Hide the layers behind it, and hit save as. You'll need to use the history pallet to get back to your original state.

Doing it quickly it looks like this:

1. Command-Click Layer
2. V for the move tool
3. C for the crop tool
4. Enter to crop
5. Hide any layers behind
6. Command-shift-S to save as
7. Use history to go back

Answer (score 0):

- Select the layer where the icon is.
- Go to **Select**, then **Load Selection**.
- Then copy it (either command-copy or control-copy).
- Create a new Photoshop file.
- Paste the icon in.
- It should still be a smart object and you may resize as needed.
- Then simply export as a png or whatever format you'd like.